# How to check if CKEditor is empty in C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, validation, ckeditor

I'm using `CKEditor`. To check if there's a value or not, I tried to use `RequiredFieldValidator`.

The `RequiredFieldValidator` works but not perfectly, I need to make sure the `CKEditor` doesn't contain anything, not even white-space.

The `RequiredFieldValidator` works when I type 1 or 2 space(s).

When I click the `space button` a third time and then click the `submit button`, the `RequiredFieldValidator` considers it valid, and data is posted.

So I created a `CustomValidator`, in the validation method, I remove all HTML tags, then I `.Trim()`, however, trimming isn't working, data is still posted, and even if I do `field.Text.Trim().Length;` the returned number isn't 0.

What needs to be done here?

The method that removes HTML tags.

```
public string StripTagsCharArray(string source)
    {
        char[] array = new char[source.Length];
        int arrayIndex = 0;
        bool inside = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
        {
            char let = source[i];
            if (let == '<')
            {
            inside = true;
            continue;
            }
            if (let == '>')
            {
            inside = false;
            continue;
            }
            if (!inside)
            {
            array[arrayIndex] = let;
            arrayIndex++;
            }
        }
        return new string(array, 0, arrayIndex);
    }
```

Comment: What is left then when you remove all HTML tags? `&nbsp;` or something? How'd you remove the HTML tags?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev I added the method that I use to remove HTML tags. When I remove them all thats left is the space, Trimming isn't working.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev I just checked the database, this is the value (without HTML decoding) `<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this trick:

```
WebUtility.HtmlDecode(field.Text).Trim();
```

for your `CustomValidator`.

Comment: After knowing that the spaces are actually `&nbsp;`, Html Decoding was the missing thing, this works for .NET 4.0 and above, and for 2.0 we can use `StringWriter myWriter = new StringWriter(); HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(field.Text, myWriter);` then `myWriter` would be the decoded string, so the only thing left was `String text = myWriter.ToString().Trim();` and then `text.Length` would be 0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in CKeditor `config.js`:

```
config.htmlEncodeOutput=false;
```